# Change array date format

Tags: vb.net, converters

The date that scan from word document which is 30/08/2012 but when it loads into my program it prints  20/10/05.
Below code have error for convert it.

`Dim str() As String`

str(1) = Convert.ToDateTime(Format("yy-MM-dd"))
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
Dim output As Date = Date.ParseExact(str(1), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: If `str(1)` value is `30/08/2012` is must recognize it. The first parameter must be the date string. Maybe it has more invalid characters: you have to get only the date string first.

Comment: i make a breakpoint.the str value is 30/08/2012.but i dunno why it execute become 20/10/05.